# How to get NSParagraphStyleAttributeName from NSMutableAttributeString?

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I create an `NSMutableAttributedString` with alignment as follows:

```
UIFont * font =  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
/// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
/// Set line break mode
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
/// Set text alignment
paragraphStyle.alignment = alignmentForString(textString) ;//NSTextAlignmentLeft;//NSTextAlignmentRight;// NSTextAlignmentNatural;//  NSTextAlignmentLeft;

NSDictionary *messageDrawRectAttributesDictionary = @{
                        NSFontAttributeName: font,
                        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]
                        };

NSMutableAttributedString * mutalbleAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textString attributes:messageDrawRectAttributesDictionary];
```

I want to know (for later use in the app)
how to get what alignment I set in this string.

I tried this code, without understanding exactly what I'm doing:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,mutalbleAttributedString.length-1);
NSDictionary * paraDic =[mutalbleAttributedString attribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName atIndex:0 longestEffectiveRange:&range inRange:range];
```

Now, I search for a lot of sample code and I read the Apple docs. But no luck. I get empty dictionary.

The only help I need is if someone can just write the right code that will return me the data of the alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `attribute:atIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:`, the return value is the value of the requested attribute, not a dictionary. Also, do not pass in `range` for both range parameters.

Your code should be something like this:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, mutalbleAttributedString.length);
NSParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [mutalbleAttributedString attribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName atIndex:0 longestEffectiveRange:NULL inRange:range];
NSTextAlignment alignment = paraStyle.alignment;
```

Note the following changes:

- The proper return value for the attribute being requested
- Settings the proper length for `range`
- Passing `NULL` for the `longestEffectiveRange:` since you don't care about that value.

Comment: great ! that's works ! thanks ! hope this help for others too!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the alignment from the NSMutableAttributedString like this:

```
 NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedString.length);
 NSDictionary *attributes = [mutableAttributedString attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:&range];
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = attributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
 NSTextAlignment alignment = paragraphStyle.alignment;
```

Comment: 1. `range` is incorrect. 2. Do not hardcode the key to get the attribute. Use the proper constant provided by the API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You are right, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** example:

```
var effectiveRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
let currentParagraphStyle: NSParagraphStyle = attributedText?.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, at: 0, effectiveRange: &effectiveRange) as! NSParagraphStyle
let align = currentParagraphStyle.alignment
let lineSpacing = currentParagraphStyle.lineSpacing
let newParagraphStyle = currentParagraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple
```